# Is it possible to have half baked extents?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is it possible to have half baked extents if we have high volume data load and lets say query fails in between while the data load to the table is going on ? So lets say we have a high volume data load going on as part of a single ingest from table query (`.set-or-append`) and since the data is huge , it's creating several extents for the table (which the cluster may later try to merge as per the merge policy applicable for the table , but that is much later , not during the data load mostly). So in a way it's a single ADX command causing data load against individual extents separately -- so what if some of the extent loads succeed and some of them fail -- will we be left with a failed command with the table partially loaded ? I am trying to make sure that if a command fails as a whole , the data does not appear in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ingestion command is atomic regardless of the number of extents it creates, either it completely fails or completely succeeds, it cannot provide partial results.

The transactional guarantees also span [update policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy), where the policy can be [transactional or non-transactional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy#treatment-of-failures). In the non-transactional case, the ingestion can succeed on the source table and fail on the target table, in the transactional case all the relevant ingestions across **all** tables that participate in the update policy chain either succeed or fail.